# AWS Cloudfront - set header REMOTE_ADDR=HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR

Tags: asp.net, iis, amazon-cloudfront

I have a website, with a HTTPS CloudFront front-end, forwarding via HTTP to an IIS website.

In various places in the application the REMOTE_ADDR header for security logging etc.

This header obviously won't work correctly through CloudFront, as it will be the cloudfront server, rather than the actual remote client address.

To avoid having to make a lot of application code changes, what I'm thinking of doing is overriding the value of REMOTE_ADDR and setting it to the value of HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR.

To do this, I was planning to put this code in the Global.asax.vb BeginRequest handler...

```
Dim remote_address = HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR")
If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(remote_address) Then
    HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables.Set("REMOTE_ADDR", remote_address)
End If
```

Is there any reason why it might be undesirable to do something like this?

It seems that this should allow the application to continue working as normal, without having to know whether it's being called directly by a client, or via CloudFront.

Comment: *"Is there any reason why it might be undesirable to do something like this?"*  There definitely is a problem with doing this. You can't trust `X-Forwarded-For` unless you can trust the previous systems that wrote it, and you certainly can't trust clients not to provide deceptive values.  A malicious user, accessing your server directly, can simply set this header... which, incidentally, can also contain multiple values.

Comment: If there was some other way I could verify that only CloudFront can access the site directly, then it should be safe?